# Como mostrar carácteres especiales provenientes de una base de datos en spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Desde Spring me conecto a una base de bados mysql, pero los datos me los carga sin acentos
tengo añadido esto a la url

```
"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Comment: El problema está en la bd o en la conexión, desde el terminal sí me muestra los datos bien, pero probe a conectarme con dbeaver y los datos los muestra mal igual

Comment: Desde la terminal (donde se ve bien) ¿que te devuelve `show variables like 'character%'`? Agrégalo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Es diferente ponerlo en la URL a ponerlo en las propiedades de Spring.

Cuando va en la URL es de esta manera

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

*Nota que aquí el `useUnicode` dice *yes* y no *true*

Si estás usando Spring Boot, te recomiendo agregar la configuración en las propiedades de `application.properties` en vez de agregarlo directamente en tu URL.

Agregalo de esta manera a tu `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```